# Printing consecutive entries as pairs from an array

Tags: c

I have an array 'a' inserted by the user as:

```
printf("insert N");
scanf ("%d", &n);
printf ("insert group of numbers");
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
```

Then, from the original array, I have to make a sequence which will have all the entries of the original array but if an entry is coming multiple times consecutively, then instead of writing that number multiple times, only two numbers should be added to the sequence: first denoting the repeated number and the second denoting its frequency. Example:

```
Array : 1,3,4,1,1,1,1,6,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,3,2,5,6,1,2,1,1,1,1,1.
Sequence: 1,3,4,1,4,6,7,1,6,9,3,2,5,6,1,2,1,5
```

The first 3 numbers are written down as they are. Then '1' comes consecutively 4 times so we append 1,4 to the sequence and so on.

Actually i m confused how i can make i and j are on the same steps,
as far as i know i and j start from 0 then 1,2,3,4
but how can I make them start each in the same step so if a[i(that is 3 in the step)] = 10
so a[j( on step 3) is 10 too?
Thanks for the time! I appreciate!

Comment: What is a, is it an array?

Comment: int a[100];I declared max 100 so mine is: a[max];

Comment: You want to overwrite the original array itself or do you want to preserve the original array and just output 1,3,4,1,4... sequence to the screen?

Comment: Even your input loop doesn't work. You need `scanf("%d", &a[i]);`. Furthermore your question should use `b[i]` instead of `a[j]` (or it is a completely different task, called "in place")

Comment: Don't understande what's a[i] mean.
a is an array so a[i] is a element of a, e.g  `a[0] = 1;`

So you want to recreate a new array for exemple b, 
where for example : 
`a = [1, 1, 1];`
`b = [1, 3];`

Comment: @DemonSlayer What are a[i] and a[j] in your example?:)

Comment: @Dante "What is a...?" I think it is the first letter of the alphabet is not it?.:)

Comment: I changed the code into this:
printf ("insert group of numbers");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a);
    }
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){

    if (a[i] == 1 && demon == 0){
        b[i] = a[i];
        demon++;
    }else if (a[i] == 1 && demon > 0){
              demon++;

    }else if(a[i] != 1 && demon > 0){
    b[i] = demon;
    demon = 0;
    }

Comment: @DemonSlayer If a is an array then how can  a[j]= a set of values a[j] can only contain a single number.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Pity guys like you, go to a mock show, u will not fail there.

Comment: @Dante, i edited my code but it's still not working..

Comment: I have written an edit, can someone approve it?

Comment: @DemonSlayer I still guessing what u want. Do you want to build a new array from original given array such that the output array looks like  1,3,4,1.....and so on.

Comment: @Nitish Garg, Thanks nitish, I approved.

Comment: @Dante yes. I actually create a new array B[i] and import things from a[i] but when a number happens more than one times I write the number, and how much times it happened like this: 1,1,1,1,1 it  in b become 1,5.

Comment: @DemonSlayer do you want to overwrite the original array itself or do you want to preserve the original array and just output 1,3,4,1,4... sequence to the screen?

Comment: @Nitish Garg, I want it to write on another array. For example in b[i].

Comment: @DemonSlayer Is it ok to assume that length of B is equal to a or first u want to calculate the exact number of elements in B to save space.

Comment: @Dante, Actually the lenght is not important, as it's ok as i declared the max is 100 :)

Comment: @DemonSlayer Where are you hurry? At first see my answer.:) I say you by secret that it is only me who can write code.L)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, I think your code is ok and working but for me (a beginner) is too much hard to understand, Thanks anyway :) !

Comment: @Dante, By the way, Why you made the main Void and not int?

Comment: @DemonSlayer Opposite to you I think it is easy to understand the code.:)

Comment: @DemonSlayer Simply copy and paste the code and try it.:) And you will like it.:)

Comment: @DemonSlayer I don't think that my code contains any bug. Kindly abstain from users who suggest you to accept their answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will do the job.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    int i,x,j=0,n,*a,*b;
    printf("insert N");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    a=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    b=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    printf ("insert group of numbers");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
     for( i=0;i<n;++i)
     {
        x=0;
            while((i+1)<n&&a[i]==a[i+1])
            {
                ++x;
                ++i;
            }
            if(x>1)
            {
             b[j++]=a[i];
             b[j++]=x+1;
            }
            else b[j++]=a[i];
     }
    for(i=0;i<j;++i)
        printf("%d  ",b[i]);

}
```

Comment: @DemonSlayer As u mentioned space is not important so I did not bothered to calculate the length of array b.

Comment: That's not it. The user have to input the numbers, they can't be already declared and, it has to be in "for" statements,

Comment: @DemonSlayer Now it will do.

Comment: @Dante  This is a demonstration how code should not be written.:)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, Why?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You probably never heard of identation.Learning new things is not bad.

Comment: @Dante Thank you guys, I will tell to my teacher i did not know how to do such a thing and ask them to explain to me the code.. If i can ask, May you comment the code please? Thanks really guys!

Comment: @DemonSlayer Do you want to understand the logic behind the code.

Comment: @DemonSlayer Which part.I am here to help.

Comment: @Dante, Thanks, 
while((i+1)<n&&a[i]==a[i+1])
            {
                ++x;
                ++i;
            }
            if(x>1)
            {
             b[j++]=a[i];
             b[j++]=x+1;
            }
            else b[j++]=a[i];
This one

Comment: @DemonSlayer Look (i+1)<n is used so that we do not go outside the array and a[i]==a[i+1] checks whether consecutive numbers are same.The while loop will execute as long as consecutive numbers are same and it will execute x times where x = number of repititions - 1, this is the reason I have b[j++]=x+1 and and not b[j++]=x, every time I fill the array b, the condition x>1 is true because we are only concerned about the elements that occur more than one.

Comment: @DemonSlayer I would advice you practise as many questions as possible. I know its hard in the beginning.I myself struggled a lot in the beginning 2, 3 months, a hell of a lot.

Comment: @Dante i appreciate your help, if you mind and if you want I would appreciate if you leave me your skype username or facebook one so if you have some time we can help eachother.. Thank you so much! Other, i understood everything so yeah :D

Comment: @Dante, why you made the main void and not int? :)

Comment: @DemonSlayer It does not matter, you can have any.

Comment: @DemonSlayer "Why?" –  because it is a bad style of writing code. You should not write code in such a style.

Comment: @DemonSlayer Don't care much about the style, a good computer scientist always craves for logic and not style.

Comment: @Dante  Ask any professional programmer and he wil say that it is a bad code. It is a code of a beginner.

Comment: @Dante  On the other hand it is good that you already can write code so quickly though it contains a bug. The understanding of a good programming style will come later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83341/discussion-between-dante-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @Dante  In gact I already said what I wanted to say.:) So I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this code will help or not, insted of arr_1 elemets you could use the scanf and load the variables

```
#include<stdio.h> int main() {
    int arr_1[]={1,3,4,1,1,1,1,6,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,3,2,5,6,1,2,1,1,1,1,1};
    int arr_2[27];
    int arr_len;
    int i,j,cntr=0;
    int flag = 0;
    arr_len=sizeof(arr_1)/sizeof(int);

    for(i=0,j=0;i<arr_len;i++)
    {

        if(arr_1[i] == arr_1[i+1])
        {
            if(flag == 0)
            {
                arr_2[j] = arr_1[i];
                j++;
            }
            flag = 1;
            cntr++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(cntr > 0)
            {
                arr_2[j] = cntr+1;
                cntr=0;
                flag = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                arr_2[j]=arr_1[i];
            }
            j++;
        }

    }


    for(i=0;i<arr_len;i++)
    printf("%d ",arr_1[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    printf("%d ",arr_2[i]);

    getch(); }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that Dante's code is more "easy"

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0, last=0, j=0, n, i;
printf("insert N");
scanf ("%d", &n);
int b[n];
printf ("insert group of numbers");
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    if(a[i] == last){
      count++;
    }
    else {
        b[j] = last;
        j++;
        if(count != 0){
            b[j] = count + 1;
            j++;
            count = 0;
        }
        last = a[i];
    }

}
```

Rather than doing post processing as a few others have suggested you can process the input as it is received.

The if statement increments the count when a duplicate is encountered.
The else statement sets the second array to the last value (not current value) when the current value is different. If the last value was a duplicate, it adds the number of duplicates in the next if statement. After that, it updates the last variable.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a demonstrative program that is based on using Variable Length Arrays (VLA). If you want you can change it such a way that instead of VLA(s) it used either arrays of fixed sizes or dynamically allocated arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "\nEnter array size: " );

        size_t n = 0;
        scanf( "%zu", &n );

        if ( !n ) break;

        int a[n];

        printf( "Enter %zu elements of the array: ", n );
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) scanf( "%d", &a[i] );

        printf( "\na[%zu] = { ", n );
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d, ", a[i] );
        printf( "}\n" );

        size_t m = 0;
        size_t count;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i += count )
        {
            count = 0;
            while ( ++count + i < n && a[count + i] == a[i] );
            m += count > 1 ? 2 : 1;  
        }

        int b[m];

        for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i += count )
        {
            count = 0;
            while ( ++count + i < n && a[count + i] == a[i] );

            b[j++] = a[i];
            if ( count > 1 ) b[j++] = count;
        }        

        printf( "b[%zu] = { ", m );
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) printf( "%d, ", b[i] );
        printf( "}\n" );
    }        
}
```

The program might have the following output

```
Enter array size: 27
Enter 27 elements of the array: 1 3 4 1 1 1 1 6 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 9 3 2 5 6 1 2 1 1 1 1 1

a[27] = { 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, }
b[18] = { 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 6, 7, 1, 6, 9, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 5, }

Enter array size: 6
Enter 6 elements of the array: 1 1 1 1 1 2

a[6] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, }
b[3] = { 1, 5, 2, }

Enter array size: 0
```

Comment: Thank you vlad! :D it's a really nice alternative way :)

Comment: @DemonSlayer It is the only code that deserves to be considered.:)

Comment: My teacher said that when a Main() code is bigger than 20 lines it's useless, and not working in the right way. Our codes are everytime 15-16 lines. :)

Comment: @DemonSlayer  Your teacher is wrong. In fact the main part of the code I showed is the following loop
        for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i += count )
        {
            count = 0;
            while ( ++count + i < n && a[count + i] == a[i] );

            b[j++] = a[i];
            if ( count > 1 ) b[j++] = count;
        }   that contains only 7 lines. All other statements are auxiliary code as for example printing the arrays.:)